# Javascript Switch to if-else

Tags: javascript

Помогите поменять форму `Switch` на `if-else`:
я сделал скрипт чтоб компьютер создал четыре цифры рандомно(от 1 до 9) и добавил их в массив arr потом в `<input>` с `id="num"` надо разгадать число если правильно то выводится `res.innerHTML` а если не правильно создается новый массив.

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    switch(num){
    case arr[0]:
        res.innerHTML = "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>";
        break;
    case arr[1]:
        res.innerHTML = "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>";
        break;
    case arr[2]:
        res.innerHTML = "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>";
        break;
    case arr[3]:
        res.innerHTML = "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>";
        break;  
    default:
        res.innerHTML = "Неправильно попробуйте угадать число снова";
        mass.onclick();
    }
```

Comment: напишите словами, что Вы хотите сделать

Comment: я сделал скрипт чтоб компьютер создал четыре цифры рандомно(от 1 до 9) и добавил их в массив `arr` потом в `<input>` с `id="num"` надо разгадать число если правильно то выводится `res.innerHTML` а если не правильно создается новый массив.

Comment: а `num` что такое?

Comment: var num = document.getElementById('num');
      num = parseInt(num.value);

Comment: Перенесите Ваши комментарии в вопрос. Из вопроса совершенно непонятно, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function checkInput(arr, num) {
  if (arr.indexOf(num) != -1)
    return "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>";  
    
  return "Неправильно попробуйте угадать число снова";   
}

console.log(checkInput([1, 5, 6, 2], 2));
console.log(checkInput([1, 5, 6, 2], 9));
console.log(checkInput([14, 2345, 234234, 42342], 30));
console.log(checkInput([14, 2345, 234234, 42342, 666], 666));
```

**[arr.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** - возвращает первый индекс, по которому данный элемент может быть найден в массиве или -1, если такого индекса нет.

Зная это, можно применить у себя данную проверку вместо `switch/case` и `if/elseif`

**P.S.** по-хорошему `checkInput` должен возвращать не надпись, а `true/false`, и от него уже танцевать. Но главное, чтоб вы уловили смысл.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(num == arr[0]){
    res.innerHTML = "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>";
} else if(num == arr[1]){ 
    res.innerHTML = "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>";
} else if(num == arr[2]){ 
    res.innerHTML = "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>";
} else if(num == arr[3]){ 
    res.innerHTML = "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>";
} else { 
    res.innerHTML = "Неправильно попробуйте угадать число снова";
    mass.onclick();
}
```

Вариант который легче поддерживать если увеличить количество цифр.

```
var check = false;
for(var i in arr){
  if(num == arr[i]){
    check = true;
    break;
  }
}
res.innerHTML = check ? "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>" : "Неправильно попробуйте угадать число снова";

if(!check){
  mass.onclick();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо но можно более коротко?

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
let res.innerHTML = (num === arr[0]) ? "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>" :
                    (num === arr[1]) ? "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>" :
                    (num === arr[2]) ? "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>" :
                    (num === arr[3]) ? "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>":
                                      "Неправильно попробуйте угадать число снова";
```

или даже так:

```
let res.innerHTML = ((num === arr[0]) || (num === arr[1]) || (num === arr[2]) || (num === arr[3])) ? 
                "Nice you right" + " : " + num + "<br>" : 
                "Неправильно попробуйте угадать число снова";
```